# How to import D3 for an Ember project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have tried `ember-d3` which does not work for me. I also have tried install D3 using NPM and `ember-broswerfiy`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import * as d3 from 'npm:d3';
```

However, I get the following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: _npmD3.select is not a function
```

Is there a way to import D3 using ES6 import instead of making it available globally?

Comment: Why is ember-d3 does not work for you? Is it v4 version which does not work - there's also ember-d3 v3 branch u can use

Comment: Browser complain that it cannot find `d3` after I installed ember-d3 (import using `import * as d3 from 'd3'`)

Comment: why don't you use import d3 from 'd3' ? I have already done a project with d3 and it's perfectly working. just as a quick tip, you may use DC also.